# System.Text.Json won't deserialize to my type even though my constructor implements every property

Tags: .net, json.net, system.text.json

I can't figure out why System.Text.Json won't deserialize this simple JSON string to my specified .NET type. I'm getting the `Each parameter in the deserialization constructor on type 'MenuItem' must bind to an object property or field on deserialization. Each parameter name must match with a property or field on the object. The match can be case-insensitive` error message, even though I have mapped every property — `name`, `url`, and `permissions` — in my `MenuItem` constructor.

[Dotnet fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m9FmB8)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var json = @"
                [
                    {
                        ""name"": ""General Info"",
                        ""url"": ""/Info"",
                        ""permissions"": []
                    },
                    {
                        ""name"": ""Settings"",
                        ""url"": ""/Settings"",
                        ""permissions"": [
                            ""Admin""
                        ]
                    }
                ]";

            Console.WriteLine(json);
            var menu = new Menu(json);
            Console.WriteLine("Deserialization success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public class Menu
{
    public Menu(string json)
    {
        var items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MenuItem>>(json);
        MenuItems = items.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public MenuItem
        (
            string name, 
            string url, 
            List<Permission> permissions
        )
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Url = url;
        this.Permissions = (permissions ?? new List<Permission>()).AsReadOnly();
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Url { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Permission> Permissions { get; }
}

public enum Permission
{
    Admin,
    FinancialReporting
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your constructor and property names differ in case.  Try setting `JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true` as shown in [JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60123376/3744182).

Comment: Very strange. Not only does the error message already say the match can be case insensitive, but because I’m deserializing through a custom constructor, it should only care about the parameter names, not the property names. I’ll test this out later once I’m near my computer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a look at your fiddle and spotted a couple of problems. [Working fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xugWwB)

1. `System.Text.Json` is case-sensitive by default ([except for web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70476556/9665021)). You can resolve this by using either `PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` or `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true` in the serializer options.
2. The second issue is outlined in [Enums as strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0#enums-as-strings)

   > By default, enums are serialized as numbers. To serialize enum names
   > as strings, use the JsonStringEnumConverter.

   You should add `JsonSerializerOptions` to resolve (1) and (2):

   ```
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions 
   {
       Converters =
       {
           new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
       },
       PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
   };
   var items = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<MenuItem>>(json, options);
   ```
3. The third issue appears to be with the binding in the constructor
   for the list of `Permissions`.  In the constructor you define a
   `List<Permission>` for the permissions parameter.  I receive the
   error in your question unless the constructor argument type matches
   the model property type *exactly*.  So, I updated the constructor to
   take a `IReadOnlyList<Permission>` and it deserializes successfully:

   ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   public MenuItem
       (
           string name, 
           string url,
           IReadOnlyList<Permission> permissions
       )
   {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Url = url;
       this.Permissions = permissions ?? new List<Permission>().AsReadOnly();
   }
   ```

   Alternatively, you could change the `Permissions` property to `List<Permission>`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67038138/9665021) to a question with a similar problem explains that this is actually a limitation of `System.Text.Json` and there is currently an open [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44428).

A working fork of your fiddle is [demoed here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xugWwB).

Comment: Am I right in assuming that if I want enums to be able to dynamically serialize to either string or numeric data types depending on the target type, I'd have to write a custom converter that uses reflection? And if so, would that reflection efficiently run just once, or does it happen `O(n)` times?

Comment: @JacobStamm did you try it? It works in my testing. To test, just edit the fiddle in my answer - you can add int *and* string values to the `permissions` array and it deserializes both correctly. Are you seeing different?

Comment: @JacobStamm maybe I misinterpreted your question. You can serialize enum values using the `JsonStringEnumConverter` in the options (just like deserializing) - if you want `int`s then serialize without the converter, if you want `string`s then use the converter in the serialization: `JsonSerializer.Serialize(MenuItems, options);`

Comment: You're right, it works with both string and int values once the string converter is added. Thank you.

Comment: Back to the non-overengineered Newtonsoft it is...

Comment: `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true` solved the problem for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution is to use

> JsonSerializable

attribute of

> System.Text.Json.Serialization

It looks like:

```
[JsonSerializable(typeof(YourClassName))]
public class YourClassName
{
    public byte YourPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

Always class and always public and always properties and always use the attribute on the class.